# How do I pass more than one variable to a form in C#

Tags: c#, forms

I am able to pass one variable to a second form from a first main form using the code below:
Form 1:

```
public void PJRating_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    //This block reads in user text box submissions
    mys = Convert.ToDouble(MYS.Text);
    tubeOD = Convert.ToDouble(TubeOD.Text);
    tubeID = Convert.ToDouble(TubeID.Text);
    tjOD = Convert.ToDouble(TJOD.Text);
    adjTens = ((Math.Pow(((((tubeOD - tubeID) * 0.95) + tubeID)), 2) - Math.Pow(tubeID, 2)) * (Math.PI / 4)) * (mys * Math.Pow(10, 3));

    //Diplay the new window
    PupJointRating newTensileRating = new PupJointRating(adjTens);
    newTensileRating.Show();
}
```

Form 2:

```
public PupJointRating(double adjTens)
{

    InitializeComponent();
    Convert.ToString(adjTens);
    string tensCap = String.Format("{0:N0}", adjTens);
    DisplayTensCap.Text = tensCap;
}
```

This code works for displaying the "adjTens" variable from the first form on the second form. However, there are other variables from this first form that I want to display on the second form and I cannot figure out how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pass additional arguments into `PupJointRating`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more arguments to the constructor of Form2. For example:

```
public PupJointRating(double adjTens, int arg1, string arg2)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Convert.ToString(adjTens);
    string tensCap = String.Format("{0:N0}", adjTens);
    DisplayTensCap.Text = tensCap;
    //Do something with arg1, arg2
}
```

Then call it by passing additional arguments:

```
int myInt= 0;
string myString = string.Empty;

//...

//Diplay the new window
PupJointRating newTensileRating = new PupJointRating(adjTens, myInt, myString);
newTensileRating.Show();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked just fine. This seemed to be the most intuitive way to do this, but intellisense kept giving me an error on the function on Form 1. I didn't realize that as long as the arguments were also added on Form 2 that Intellisense would let it pass. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. You could expand your current `Form2` constructor like so:

```
public PupJointRating(double adjTens, double secondParam)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Convert.ToString(adjTens);
    string tensCap = String.Format("{0:N0}", adjTens);
    DisplayTensCap.Text = tensCap;
    //do something with secondParam
}
```

And then in your first form you'd do something like this:

```
PupJointRating pjr = new PupJointRating(myDoubleVar, myOtherDoubleVar);
```

Or you can simply just add a second constructor with additional arguments as described above. Doing this gives you the option of creating a `PupJointRating` object with either just one single argument passed to it, or two:

```
var pjr1 = new PupJointRating(myDoubleVar);
var pjr2 = new PupJointRating(myDoubleVar, myOtherDoubleVar);
```

Both of those would then be valid lines of code and give you an object.

This is called [member overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx) and is both very common, and very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to declare some data transfer class, for instance:

```
public class SecondFormParams
{
    public string ArgumentOne {get;set;}
    public string ArgumentTwo {get;set;}
}
```

Add this as argument for second forms:

```
public PupJointRating(SecondFormParams secondFormParams)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string tensCap = String.Format("{0:N0}", secondFormParams.ArgumentOne);
    DisplayTensCap.Text = tensCap;
    //Do something with other params, like: secondFormParams.ArgumentTwo
}
```

And populate this object with params and then show the second form:

```
public void PJRating_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Init your transfer object
    var sfp = new SecondFormParams();

    //This block reads in user text box submissions
    mys = Convert.ToDouble(MYS.Text);
    tubeOD = Convert.ToDouble(TubeOD.Text);
    tubeID = Convert.ToDouble(TubeID.Text);
    tjOD = Convert.ToDouble(TJOD.Text);
    sfp.ArgumentOne = ((Math.Pow(((((tubeOD - tubeID) * 0.95) + tubeID)), 2) - Math.Pow(tubeID, 2)) * (Math.PI / 4)) * (mys * Math.Pow(10, 3));
    sfp.ArgumentTwo = "Yo man, do something with me on the next form";
    //Diplay the new window
    PupJointRating newTensileRating = new PupJointRating(sfp);
    newTensileRating.Show();
}
```

Using this approach you can easily define some additional properties for transfer object and pass this without changing arguments for second form.